# You have already activated rack 1.6.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.6.4. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rack, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I'm working with Elastic Beanstalk and I'm getting this error in my logs-

> You have already activated rack 1.6.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.6.4. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)

I've seen all related questions([Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241912/how-to-force-rack-to-work-around-the-usual-you-have-already-activated-rack)) but nothing worked for me.
When I do `gem list | grep rack` i get-

> rack (1.6.4)
>   rack-test (0.6.3)

That means I don't have rack(1.6.0) installed, which is confirmed when I do `gem uninstall rack -v 1.6.0` it gives me-

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
>       gem "rack" is not installed

What should I do? Should I uninstall rack 1.6.4? (that gives me a warning that I won't have any rack versions)

Comment: What does it say in your Gemfile.lock? I would run a bundle update rack. Maybe you have it locked at 1.6.0?

Comment: I tried bundle update rack and it said 'Using rack 1.6.4'(along with all other gems) and this is my gemfile.lock http://textuploader.com/al5o1. It has rack 8 different times and i don't know what it exactly means.

Comment: I would try to delete your Gemfile.lock and run bundle again. There's a dependency issue somewhere. Failing that, I would roll back to rack 1.6.0 unless you really need 1.6.4...

Comment: I deleted my Gemfile.lock and ran bundle, didnt help. I rolled back to 1.6.0 but when i do bundle install after that, it installls 1.6.4 as well. So then i have both versions.

Comment: I think its happening because i have the gem unicorn in my gemfile and that gem has a dependency on rack >= 0 and thats why both versions gets installed but i don't why it only shows 1 version to me and how to fix it

Comment: Thanks it worked. I rolled back to 1.6.0 and locked it at this version so that it doesnt update when i do bundle install and that did the trick. i think that unicorn was installing 1.6.0 on runtime so i just removed 1.6.4 altogether.

Answer (score 6):

There appears to be some sort of sniffing of the gemfile going on. Try adding your ruby server to the gemfile explicitly e.g.

`gem 'puma'`

This convinced EB to load the rack specified in the Gemfile in my case.

Comment: Yes this worked for me too! I was racking(hehe) my brains trying to figure out how to get EB to use the rack version I wanted. I guess you could probably specify the rack version in your Gemfile too? I needed puma so this works tho.

Answer (score -3):

I deleted my gemlock file and push my app to production . Then i get into my root-app folder of hosting . and ran the following command and it made my app work properly

```
gem install rack
```